# How to prevent timeout when running a time consuming PHP

Tags: php, timeout, webserver

I am using PHP that gets so many data from several sites and write those data to the server which make files greater than 500 MB, but the process fails in between giving a 500 INTERNAL ERROR, how to adjust the timeout time of the php so that the process runs till it is completed.

Comment: Don't run long tasks from the web SAPI, run them from the CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase the maximum execution time for your scripts, then just change the value of the following setting in your php.ini file-

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

If you want more memory for your scripts, then change this-

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

One more thing, if you keep on processing the input(GET or POST), then you need to increase this as well-

```
max_input_time = 60
```

Comment: I don't have a php.ini file on my website, how to make one and where to put it, also I am using a sub-domain, and the php that took lot of time is inside some folders

Comment: Are you using Shared Hosting?

Comment: I have access to myname.domain.com
Not domain.com

Comment: Do you have access to the Server Setting files?

Comment: I have a FTP access to the sub-domain name.domain.com and I use a file managet PHP script to open it on browser.

Comment: For this problem, you should probably Google something like "How to edit php.ini on YOUR_HOSTING_COMPANY". That would help you the best.

Comment: What do you mean by YOUR_HOSTING_COMPANY?

MY_HOSTING_COMPANY is GoDaddy
and in my url name.domain.com
domain is the website of my admin, who is a person I can contact

Comment: Should I contact him or search for How to edit php.in on GoDaddy?

Comment: Better contact him, because he would have access to the Server Setting Files.

Comment: Ok, but what are server setting files?

Comment: They store all settings on which your server runs. Google for more info.

Answer (score -1):

you have to set some settings in the php.ini to solve this problem.
There are some options which could be the problem.
Could you pls post your php.ini config?
Which kind of webserver do you use?Apache?